# Search specific word and delete it from file in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file (file1.txt) which contains below text:

```
mon
tue
tue_day
tuesday
wed
```

and I want to search for a word "tue" and delete it from this file.
I used

```
sed -i "/tue/d" file1.txt
```

but it deletes all the lines containing tue word i.e. line 2,3 and 4. I want to delete the only line 2 which conatins exact same text that i want to remove from file.

could you please suggest?

Comment: google `regexp tutorial` and take it.

Answer (score 3):

Just tell `sed` that you want lines that are exactly "tue". How? Prepending and appending `^` and `$` to indicate beginning and end of line:

```
$ sed '/^tue$/d' file
mon
tue_day
tuesday
wed
```

To replace with something given in a variable, use double quotes like this:

```
var="tue"
sed -i "/^$var$/d" file
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...
one more query how do I use variable in place of "tue" in sed command?
like now I use:
sed -i "/$var/d" file

Comment: @SagarPatil just say `var="tue"` and then `sed -i "/^$var$/d" file`. Note you have to use double quotes to have the variables expanded. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Consider making the section of your script exposed to shell as brief as possible: `sed -i '/^'"$var"'$/d' file`. I don't think it'll matter in this case but it's a more robust style to get into the habit of using so you aren't surprised by gothcas when your scripts get larger and/or more complicated.